# Why is :required => true not working on collection_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to make sure the user selects a category in my form before they can submit it, but `:required => true` doesn't seem to be working. Here's the select:

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, :prompt => 'Choose a category' %>
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 14):

Try this

```
<%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => 'Choose a category'}, {:required => true}) %>
```

Explanation:

According to the Rails documentation the syntax for the `collection_select` function looks like this:

```
collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

As per the syntax `options` and `html_options` are hashes, so you need to enclose them in braces.

Reference - http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select

Comment: You may want to add a little explanation (and maybe additionally a link to a reference) why curly brackets need to be put around the properties.