# Required Field on collection_select type field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, field, form-for

I have a form with a simple text field where I require the form to be filled out:

```
<%= f.text_field :email, :required => true %>
```

The next field is a collection_select type where I want to force the user to select a choice. I tried:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:list_ids, List.where(user_id: current_user), :id, :name, {}, {multiple: true}), :required => true %>
```

which gives me the error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' ..., :name, {}, {multiple: true}), :required => true );@output_... ... ^
```

Without the `:required => true` option the code works fine. How do I force a selection by the user in this case? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is :required => true not working on collection\_select?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24767768/why-is-required-true-not-working-on-collection-select)

Comment: Consider select my answer as accepted answer, that way other people in the community will help you when you have more questions...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try changing this

```
<%= f.collection_select(:list_ids, List.where(user_id: current_user), :id, :name, {}, {multiple: true}), :required => true %>
```

to this

```
<%= f.collection_select :list_ids, List.where(user_id: current_user), :id, :name, {}, {multiple: true, required: true} %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<%= f.collection_select(:list_ids, List.where(user_id: current_user), :id, :name, {}, {multiple: true, required: true}) %>
```

Explanation:

According to the Rails documentation the syntax for the collection_select function looks like this:

```
collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

As per the syntax options and html_options are hashes, so you need to enclose them in braces.

Reference - http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select

[Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24767768/why-is-required-true-not-working-on-collection-select/24767913#24767913)

Comment: your answer was copied almost line for line from this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24767768/why-is-required-true-not-working-on-collection-select/24767913#24767913) if your going to copy, you should credit that persons answer

Comment: Yes you are right, actually I was about to mark this as dup

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= form.collection_select :msr_cd, 
    @msrs, :msr_cd, :msr_cd,
      {multiple: false, required: true},
      data: { placeholder: "Select Measure" }, 
      class: "form-control col-sm-12 chosen-select"  
%>

Note:
    @msrs from the controller
    :msr_cd - option value`enter code here`
    :msr_cd - option text

We can pass the chosen select like above
```